# char array and pointer -- can somebody explain the following output?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand the special relationship that exists between array and pointers i.e. an array name without the brackets always points to the first element of the array.

On a Linux system, I get this with a C program:

```
char name[7] = "unique";

printf("\nAddress stored of name: %p", name); 
printf("\nAddress stored of name: %s", name); //Conflict
printf("\nAddress of name[0]: %p", &name[0]);

//dereferencing the pointer
printf("\nValue of name[0]: %c", *name);
printf("\nValue of name[1]: %c", *(name+1));
```

The output is:

```
Address stored of name: 0xbff68131
Address stored of name: unique
Address of name[0]: 0xbff68131
Value of name[0]: u
Value of name[1]: n
```

I understand everything in the above output except the output of the line of code which as **//Conflict**. In other words, if **name** is equivalent to **&name[0]** as per the special relationship between array and pointers, then why simply changing the format specifier (from %p to %s) prints the actual value of the array. If that is truly the case, then does that mean **name**, **&name[0]** and ***name** are all equivalent?

I would at least expect it (//Conflict) to print some other (garbage?) value but not the actual value of the array.

Comment: "Why simply changing the format specifer ... prints the actual value"?  Because that's the whole point of choosing a different format specifier.  Different format specifiers tell `printf` to handle the corresponding argument differently.

Comment: Or think about this: if you were printing an `int` using `%d` versus `%X`, you would get different output for the same numerical value.  So why does it surprise you that different format specifiers might print different interpretations of the same address?

Comment: @jamesdlin I do understand that different format specifiers will print different values and I acknowledge that already in my question - "I would at least expect it (//Conflict) to print some other (garbage?) value but not the actual value of the array." Perhaps I misunderstood the point and array relationship here.

Comment: Wait... you understand pointers but not printing strings? Where the heck are you learning C?

Comment: @modest: How do you think something like `fputs` works?  Now why would you think that if you ask `printf` to print a string via `%s` that it would do something differently? `printf` is doing the sane thing that you asked it to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
%s
```

This tells `printf` to treat the argument as a pointer to a memory location which contains an array of characters, and prints each one until the `\0` is encountered.

```
%p
```

This treats the arguement as a memory location and prints its value in hex, as you have seen.

What you are terming as "Conflict" is actually by far the more important use, and is the correct way to print c-strings.

Answer (score -1):

When an array expression is used in place of a pointer expression, the array expression is converted to a pointer to the first element. The pointer to the first element is `array+0` or `&array[0]`, and the first element is `*(array+0)` or `array[0]`.

In `printf("\nAddress stored of name: %p", name);`, the array expression is converted to a pointer to the first element. Likewise for `printf("\nAddress stored of name: %s", name);`, name is converted to a pointer to `name[0]`. Adding 1 results in a pointer to `name[1]`. Adding 2 results in a pointer to `name[2]`, etc.

It might be worthwhile noting that the `array[n]` operator is actually a `pointer[n]` operator, that `array` gets converted to a pointer to the first expression. n gets added to the pointer to yield a pointer to the nth element, which is then dereferenced to yield the nth element from it's pointer. This occurs as a result of the `%s` format specifier. However, the `%p` format specifier doesn't do any dereferencing at all.

> If that is truly the case, then does that mean name, &name[0] and
>   *name are all equivalent?

No. `name` is an array expression: `sizeof name` will result in 7. `&name[0]` is a pointer expression that translates to "the pointer to name[0]": `sizeof &name[0]` will result in `sizeof (char *)`.  `*name` is a char expression that translates to "the char pointed to by name". `sizeof *name` will result in 1.